# H2O DistributedRandomForest all tree predictions

Tags: python, tree, random-forest, h2o

I use Python's H2O (version 3.22.1.3), and I was wondering if it is possible to observe each tree's predictions in the Random Forest, like we do in the case of scikit-learn's RandomForestRegressor.estimators_ method. I tried to use h2o.predict_leaf_node_assignment(), but it brings either the prediction path for each tree or (supposedly) the id of the leaf node based on which the prediction was made. In the last version, H2O added the Tree class, but unfortunately, it does not have any predict() method. Although I can access any node in any of the random forest's trees, still my implementation of the tree predict function using the tree's recently implemented API (even if any correct), is extremely slow. So, my question is:

(a) Can I obtain tree predictions natively, and if yes, then how?

(b) If no, do the H2O developers plan to implement this feature in future releases?

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Thank you, Joe, for your response. As for now (before the feature is directly implemented), here is the only workaround I could think of which generates tree predictions.

```
# Suppose we have random forest model called drf with ntrees=70 and want to make predictions on df_valid
# After executing the code below, we get a dataframe tree_predictions with ntrees (in our case 70) columns, where i-th column corresponds to the predictions of i-th tree, and the same number of rows as df_valid.
# Extract the trees to create prediction intervals
# Number of trees
ntrees = 70

from h2o.tree import H2OTree
# Extract all the tree of drf, create the list of prediction trees
list_of_trees = [H2OTree(model = drf, tree_number = t, tree_class = None) for t in range(ntrees)]

# leaf_nodes contains the node_id's of tree leaves with predictions
leaf_nodes = drf.predict_leaf_node_assignment(df_valid, type='Node_ID').as_data_frame()

# tree_predictions is the dataframe with predictions for all the 70 trees
tree_predictions = pd.DataFrame(columns=['T'+str(t+1) for t in range(ntrees)])
for t in range(ntrees):
    tr = list_of_trees[t]
    node_ids = np.array(tr.node_ids)
    treePred = lambda n: tr.predictions[np.where(node_ids==n)[0][0]] 
    tree_predictions['T'+str(t+1)] = leaf_nodes['T'+str(t+1)].apply(treePred)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the answer is no. We've created an issue for implementing a new feature in the Tree API. You can track the progress here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6322.